# Opening & executing .xaml in windows form

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I was wondering how can I run .xaml forms (wpfapplication) in windows form? Plus another question is, I have 2 projects ; windows form application & wpf application, i would like to combine this two and make it dependable to each others such that if I click a button on the Wpfapplication, i would call or execute a method in the windows application. is this even possible? Any help/guide would really be appreciated!

Comment: StackOverlow isn't a substitute for google.

Comment: @corlettk: The problem with this question is not that it is easy to answer but that it is a duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can host WPF controls inside Winforms. You want to have a look at the [`ElementHost` class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost.aspx).

For your other problem: If you are talking about combining the sources of both applications and basically make one executable for them then it essentially comes down to calling library functions - so thats possible. If you are talking about two independent applications in two separate processes then then it gets more complicated: you would need to add an interface to your applications exposing the methods to be called. There are many ways to do that: WCF, .Net remoting, Sockets.

Answer (score 0):

[Host WPF Controls in Windows Forms](http://nayyeri.net/host-windows-forms-controls-in-wpf)

[Host Windows Forms Controls in WPF](http://nayyeri.net/host-windows-forms-controls-in-wpf)